# How to move a Google map to new address without recreating it?

Tags: google-maps

Suppose the map has been fully drawn.
Now, the user may insert a new address and click "go there".
Can the map be moved to the new address without creating the map again?

Just to be clear, after the map was drawn can I avoid using again:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

and instead use something like

```
map.goTo(<new address>);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that you need is panTo.

See the [Google Maps Javascript API V3 Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) for more information.

```
panTo(latLng:LatLng)
```

> Changes the center of the map to the given LatLng. If the change is
>   less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be
>   smoothly animated.